# I have a smaller project but there was a problem

Tags: php, http-headers

**[11-Jul-2020 16:30:39 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE in /home/lunagzdp/s1.lunar.run/req.php on line 36 : error_log**

I do not know how to solve

```php
<?php
    ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
        session_start();
        
        function get_client_ip(){
            $ipaddress = '';
            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
                $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) //VestaCP na CF wypluwa [ip, ip]
                $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
                $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
            else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
                $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
                $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
            else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
                $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']))
                $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
            else
                $ipaddress = 's1.lunar.run';
         
            return $ipaddress;
        }
        
        $ip = get_client_ip();
        
        include('settings.php');
        const main_table = 'players';
         36 line -> $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2); <-
        function isMobile() {
            return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
        }
```

Thanks you for help!

Comment: You're wrapping every call to HTTP headers in `isset()` except that.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Ramiz Kongulov said, different browsers send header information in different ways. I would also add that you should be careful when accessing elements in an array as PHP would throw
`Undefined Index` errors if they are not available. Make use of the **null coalescing operator (??)** and **ternary operator (?:)** to avoid such errors in your application.

In your case, on line 36, you could do something like this

```
$lang = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2) : 'en';
```

You are likely to receive an error on line 38 as well.

Comment: Check out ternary operators at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 0):

Its content is sent by the browser. Different browsers send information in different ways. They can text or they can be an array. And sometimes they may not send at all.

In your case default value can be returned by next way:

```
$lang = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) 
    ? substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2) : 'en';
```

Comment: This is still likely to throw an error if you don't check with `isset()`